# How to Paste Selected Text in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a Question that is how to paste the selected or copied text on stage or text area in flash as3? I had copied text but don't have any idea about how to paste the text into text field.
Help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried simple Ctrl V ?

Comment: yes but ctrl+v works outside the flash like notepad,wordpad etc. I want to paste text on stage or any text area box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have got the answer:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.desktop.Clipboard;
    import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;
    import flash.desktop.ClipboardTransferMode;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.system.System;

    public class ClipboardExample extends Sprite
    {
       public function ClipboardExample()  
       {     
           Clipboard.generalClipboard.clear(); 
           copyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, copyText);
       }

       private function copyText(e:MouseEvent):void 
       {
           Clipboard.generalClipboard.clear();
           System.setClipboard(myField.text);
           messageField.text = "Copied!";
           stage.addEventListener(Event.PASTE,paste); //Ctrl+V on stage
       }       

       private function paste(e:Event):void
       {
          if(Clipboard.generalClipboard.hasFormat(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT))
          {                 
             messageField.text = String(Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT));
          } 
      }
   }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean myTextField.text = copiedTextVariable;?

Comment: I want to paste text on stage or any text area box.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.system.System;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;

    public class SelectTextTest extends Sprite {
        public function SelectTextTest() {
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();
            tf.x = 0;
            tf.y = 0;
            tf.width = 200;
            tf.height = 200;
            addChild(tf);
            tf.wordWrap = true;
            tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            tf.text = "This is the text. Try to select";
            tf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, printCursorPosition);
        }

        private function printCursorPosition(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var tf:TextField = TextField(event.target);
            trace("caretIndex:", tf.caretIndex);
            trace("selectionBeginIndex:", tf.selectionBeginIndex);
            trace("selectionEndIndex:", tf.selectionEndIndex);
            trace(tf.text.substring(tf.selectionBeginIndex, tf.selectionEndIndex));
            System.setClipboard(tf.text.substring(tf.selectionBeginIndex, tf.selectionEndIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to paste the copied text into text area?

Answer (score 0):

Since Flash Player 10, flash embedded on websites apps are just able to access to the Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData() method just when they are processing a PASTE event dispatched directly by the user.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html

NOTE: In order to avoid the exception security, the target of the event must be the stage object of the application.
I didn't found this information in any documentation, it is from my own experience. Hope it works